# asp.net visual studio debugging, where to ask?

Tags: discussion

doing an asp.net app that will read/write to SQL database.  Using Entity Framework to create the basic interface.

web capture tool showed alot of activity, is it allowed to ask a question related to this?  if not, where can such an HTTP question get asked?  do not know why debugging a visual studio app is so offensive the question gets deleted